# Bash doesn't respect newline in command substitution with cat

Tags: bash, command, newline, substitution, cat

Supposing we have a file list.txt:

```
line 1
line 2
```

if I use this:

```
for line in $(cat list.txt)
do 
echo $line"_"
done
```

Even if I do:

```
OLD_IFS=$IFS
$IFS='$'
```

I get:

```
line1
line2_
```

and not:

```
line1_
line2_
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Why would you even want to mess with `IFS` for this trivial job?

Comment: Unable to reproduce.  Are you sure you're using bash?

Comment: `IFS='$'` (don't use `$` for assignments) causes word-splitting on a literal dollar sign; it's not a regular expression.

Comment: A `for` loop is never appropriate for iterating over the lines of a file anyway; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001.

Comment: Yes to test you need to divide numbers. I'm going to fix it...

Comment: The problem if I use normal version when in a line there's a space it that it splits all words

Comment: @Salvio: (or) Just use a simple `Awk` statement `awk '{print $0"_"}' list.txt`

Comment: Also see [Why you shouldn't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). And feel free to link to the place you got your existing practice from -- there's a lot of misinformation/bad content in the bash tag; if you bring it to our attention we can try to correct it.

Comment: If you really just want to append an underscore, you can also use `sed 's/$/_/' list.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring your incorrect assignment `$IFS='$'`, `$` does not mean newline, linefeed or end-of-line. It means literal dollar sign.

To assign a line feed, use

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

However, do not attempt to use this to iterate over lines. Instead, use a `while read` loop, which will not expand globs or collapse empty lines:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo "${line}_"
done < file
```

or with similar benefits, read the lines into an array with `mapfile`:

```
mapfile -t lines < file
for line in "${lines[@]}"
do
  echo "${line}_"
done
```

Comment: $IFS='$' To be honest I found it here on another answer

Comment: @Salvio The other answer may have said `$ IFS='$'` where the first `$` was intended to show an interactive shell prompt. It should not be part of a script. Otherwise, it's just wrong. This is invalid syntax.

Comment: @Salvio If there's an answer here suggesting `IFS='$'` to split on linefeeds, it's pretty seriously wrong and should be fixed. Can you point it out?